# How to print the output out of for loop when users in enters inputs

Tags: python, list, for-loop, printing

In the following code user enters `N` pairs of input and each time when user enters value `2`, the most recent pair will be deleted and when value `3` is entered it prints the max of 2nd elements of the remaining tuples. Assume the input list is `B=[(1,26),(1,20),2,3,(1,91),3]`. The output should be printed like below:

```
26
91
```

But it prints after entering the associated tuple like below. Also, I just need the 2nd element of the tuples being printed:

```
6

1 26

1 20

2

3
1 26

1 91

3
1 91
```

```
N = int(input())
B=[]
for i in range(N):
    b = (input().split())
    if len(b)==2:
        B.append(b)
    if b == ['2']:
        del B[-1]  
    if b == ['3']:     
       print(*max(B,key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

Comment: Did you mean: `print(max(B,key=lambda x:x[1])[1])`?

Comment: Yes, that helped, but I am wondering how to print output after the user entered all the inputs not while he is entering input.

Comment: Just add code below the for loop.

Comment: If I add print(max(B,key=lambda x:x[1])[1]) below for loop it will be unindented. Or I misunderstood you.

Comment: Yes, unindented. Or, if indented will still be inside the loop. So, remove the last `if` and unindent the `print` right back to the left hand side.

Comment: Sorry, still I am not sure I understand you. If I remove the last if I will miss the last condition. I appreciate If show me in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see what you want.

This code snippet reads all your inputs first, just collecting them. Then it iterates through the inputs and obeys the instructions:

```py
N = int(input('Enter Number of Inputs: '))
inputs = []
for i in range(N):
    inputs.append(input().split())
    
B = []
for b in inputs:
    if len(b) == 2:
        B.append(b)
    if b == ['2']:
        del B[-1]  
    if b == ['3']:
       print(max(B,key=lambda x:x[1])[1])
```

Output as required.